# Volley request retry policy doesn't consider timeout

Tags: java, android, android-volley, request-timed-out, retrypolicy

I've set 1500 as **initialTimeoutMs** in **DefaultRetryPolicy** as below but it doesn't consider the timeout:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1500
        , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES
        , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

I disconnected the WiFi on my device to test it's timeout and I saw these times in the **Logcat**:

```
2019-12-16 14:28:15.892 I/MyClass: request sent
2019-12-16 14:28:35.930 I/MyClass: request caught onError
```

It took more than 20 seconds while I expected to catch either onResponse or onError after 1.5 seconds!!!

Comment: I believe that there is a retry logic after a backoff. So the request is sent, after 1.5  secs it times out and then retries after some random time. Overall the number of retires is DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES

Comment: what is your value for max_tries and backoff_multiplies ?

Comment: Both of them have default values. in DefaultRetryPolicy.java:
`public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 1;`
`public static final float DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT = 1f;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your configure. Your timeout should be 3 secs. 
Referring to http://prasadthangavel.blogspot.com/2013/12/why-volley-android-has-provided-two.html

***I think you should make DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT zero.***

Answer (score 0):

Use 5 sec because 15 sec it much more for giving in timeout..

```
int TIME_OUT = 500; //use 5 sec it will work fine with it..

request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    TIME_OUT, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```